# Building R package: Undocumented S4 classes (it is documented!)

Tags: r, cran

I'm building an R package with "Reference Class" (RC) classes. Now I'm preparing for CRAN submission.

My main exported class looks like this:

```
#' Oceans 2.0 API Client Library
#'
#' Provides convenient & easy access to Ocean Networks Canada's data.
#' For detailed information and usage examples, visit our
#' \href{https://wiki.oceannetworks.ca/display/O2A/R+Client+Library}{official Documentation}.
#'
#' @name Onc
#' @field token character. User token
#' @field showInfo logical. Print verbose debug comments
#' @field timeout numeric. Number of seconds before a request to the API is canceled
#' @field baseUrl character. Base URL for API requests
#' @field outPath character. Output path for downloaded files
#'
#' @export Onc
#' @exportClass Onc
Onc <- setRefClass("Onc",
    fields = list(
        token    = "character",
        showInfo = "logical",
        timeout  = "numeric",
        baseUrl  = "character",
        outPath  = "character"
    ),

    methods = list(
    (...)
```

When I build and check my package, I get the following warning:

> Undocumented S4 classes:
>       ‘Onc’   All user-level objects in a package (including S4 classes and methods)   should have documentation entries.   See chapter
>   ‘Writing R documentation files’ in the ‘Writing R   Extensions’ manual.

It's not even a S4 class, but a reference class, and I believe it's well documented. How do I pass this check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 month later, I answer my own question:

It was the documentation format (which is badly documented as most new things in R). The following worked perfectly, notice the difference with the original docstring:

```
#' Onc Class
#'
#' Provides convenient & easy access to Ocean Networks Canada's data.
#' For detailed information and usage examples, visit our
#' \href{https://wiki.oceannetworks.ca/display/O2A/R+Client+Library}{official Documentation}.
#'
#' @field token character. User token
#' @field showInfo logical. Print verbose debug comments
#' @field timeout numeric. Number of seconds before a request to the API is canceled
#' @field baseUrl character. Base URL for API requests
#' @field outPath character. Output path for downloaded files
#'
#' @exportClass Onc
Onc <- setRefClass("Onc",
    fields = list(
```